# Deleting row with javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
echo "<td><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"delete_row($row[0])\" style=\"text-decoration: none\">Delete</a></td>";

function delete_row(id){
    alert("test");
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this part?'))
    {
        window.location.href='Chassis/delete_query_chassis.php?delete_id='+id;
    }
}
```

Hi, I'm not sure what the problem with my code is, the code was working last night but suddenly it doesn't. I have a table and each row has the ability to delete. The delete text is suppose to trigger this javascript function which then delete's the row. However, the case is that the javascript function doesn't even run. The alert("test") doesn't even run.

I also tried this however the same thing happens:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"javascript:delete_row($row[0])\" style=\"text-decoration: none\">Delete</a></td>";
```

Comment: Can you post full code ? With this, It is hard to check for problem

Comment: I would suggest replacing your /" 's with single quotes ('). Maybe it will work that way...

Comment: why not just use `echo 'your td stuff here';`  that way you don't have to escape all those double quotes.

Comment: I test your code but nothing error found you may check your developer tool console.

Comment: @IncredibleHat you only need to do that if the index is a quoted string.

Comment: Check the element in the browser's DOM inspector to see if the `onclick` attribute looks correct.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Did you try rebooting the machine?

Comment: @Barmar How do I check Javascript console? Info: I'm on a mac and this code is on localhost

Comment: @Barmar Ah. Well I never toss garbage like that into double quotes anyways (as its unreadable nonsense). I always dot concat-in variables ;) So I was under the thought that his problem was that he needed even more nonsense with the extra curly braces to make it 'not foul up'. Nevermind! :)

Comment: @BarrichelloNoor In Chrome, it's View->Developer->Developer Tools.

Comment: @IncredibleHat To each his own, I find it *more* readable than lots of dot concatenation. I also sometimes use `sprintf()`, although the distance between the placeholders and the variables can make it error prone.